# top directory package not detected even if marked as sources root

Tags: module, pycharm

I have a project whose top directory is not detected as a package by PyCharm even when marked as a sources root.

What is wrong?

[image]

(Note that adding an `__init__.py` file does not help, nor should it since I am using Python 3.8)

Comment: Change your import to `from sun import Sun`. Marking `dummy` as source root adds it to `sys.path` so its **content** is available for import, not the directory itself.